# create_directory() vs. create_directories()

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, mingw-w64

Currently I am trying to work with the `std::filesystem`. I'm working on Windows 7 64-bit using MinGW-W64 GCC 7.1.0. Since this compiler does not support the `std::filesystem`, I have to include the experimental version and link with `-lstdc++fs`.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

This worked fine up to the point where I wanted to create nested directories. If I create the directories one at a time using `create_directory()`, everything works perfect. Now if I use `create_directories()` instead, it throws a `filesystem_error` if one of the directories already exists.

```
fs::path levelA{"."};
fs::path levelB{"folder"};
fs::path levelAB = levelA / levelB;  // "./folder"

bool create_separately; // set this bool as needed

if (create_separately) {
  /* This works perfectly */
  fs::create_directory(levelA);
  fs::create_directory(levelAB);
}
else {
  /* This throws because "." already exists */
  fs::create_directories(levelAB);
}
```

Comparing the documentation of the [experimental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory) version to the [standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) version, an additional sentence was added for the standard version:

> Executes (1) for every element of p that does not already exist. If p already exists, the function does nothing (this condition is not treated as an error).

Why was this treated as an error in the first place? Is this considered a bug?

Additionaly, is there an easy way to update GCC on Windows? I read something about GCC 8.1.0 being released and some new MinGW version supporting it, but I can't seem to find any downloads.

Comment: "Additionaly, is there an easy way to update GCC on Windows?" - download sources and compile them with current MinGW version.

Comment: @KorbenDose, check out the [defects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory#Defect_reports) where `noexcept` is removed

Comment: @codekaizer As I see it, the `noexcept`never was there for the version of `create_directories` I am using. I probably wasn't clear on the error: The error is not thrown due to memory allocation problems but because the path "." already exists. Since `create_directories` is documented as calling `create_directory` for every path along the way that doesn't exist, it shouldn't throw just as `create_directory`doesn't throw.

Comment: If boost is an option, I'd recommend sticking to boost::filesystem until std::filesystem is properly implemented.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, you are correct. I just **edited** the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant this, but note that only the second sentence you quoted is changed relative to the TS version—and has changed again since this question was asked.  It refers to the case where `p` already exists and might not be a *directory*; the function returns `false` to indicate that it did nothing, but at the time of asking it didn’t report any *error*, regardless of the nature of `p`.  The logic was that most operating systems do not distinguish this situation, so it was left to the application developer to ask, if they care.

It [was added](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/filesystem/create_directory&diff=prev&oldid=99199) as a result of an [LWG issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2935); the meaning of the previous wording was unclear at best, with no explanation of what happened if the function failed to satisfy its stated postcondition.  There is no general notion of “postcondition failure is an error”, but rather that “postcondition failure in the absence of a reported error is logically impossible”.

Since the initial version of this answer, a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1164r1.pdf) was accepted that changed it to be an error if and only if the conflicting object is not a directory, requiring a subsequent check on many platforms.  This is unusual for C++, but the result was thought to be more intuitive and the operation is relatively expensive anyway.

Regardless, the reason your implementation fails on `.` would seem to be that it’s buggy.  (I don’t have any special hints about how to most easily obtain a newer version.)